# A confusion about radial schemes in power distribution

Tags: power-engineering

My lecture notes about distribution systems/radial schemes say the following:

•In this scheme, feeders radiate from a substation in all
directions and feed distributors at one end only.

• SA is the feeder which feeds the distributor BC at its end B.

The lecture includes the following picture of a radial scheme:

[image]

**Question:** How does this form a complete circuit ? Put differently, the service lines are not part of a circuit as far as I can see.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking at a [single-line diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-line_diagram). Each of those feeders is actually a three-phase AC transmission line.

We draw three-phase circuits as single lines to simplify the drawing, because drawing three parallel lines for every single feeder clutters up the drawing and doesn't convey any extra information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the single-line diagram of distribution networks very confusing, and this detailed diagram of `IEEE-1992-13Bus` clarifies everything.

[image]

*https://mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/examples/ieee-13-node-test-feeder.html*

Compared to its single-line diagram:

[image]